# How to detect changing controllers in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

So here's what I'm wondering...

Without storing a value in session or in a cookie, is there an easy way in MVC to detect when the controller in focus is changed? Say for example a user navigates from a page within the "Home" controller to a page within the "Account" controller. Does MVC have any built in functionality to make it easy to detect this?

I'm trying to warn users when they leave a certain page (when they try to exit out of a Wizard) and I'm having a hard time figuring out a simple solution.

Comment: Um. JavaScript on the page?

Comment: Look into the "onbeforeunload" event in JavaScript. However, that event fires for any page navigation, which means you can't (to my knowledge) conditionally fire it based on the page that they are GOING to. In your case, I'd find a way to change the requirement. How about storing the partially filled out wizard with AJAX so that the user can just leave, then come back if they left by accident, without starting over again.

Comment: Graham, thanks for your comment. I've thought about using onbeforeunload but you're absolutely right - I can't conditionally fire it based on the target page. Allowing for the user to leave and return the wizard may be my best option.